# Remove permissions on sysobjects table for db user sql 2012 like in ms sql 2000

Tags: permissions, sql

In a bygone age in ms sql 2000, if I wanted to remove a db users ability to view the sysobjects table in Ent. Manager I'd find the user in the database, right click him, select properties and then click permissions, scrolls down to sysobjects and put a 'x' into the ability to select.

I can't figure out how to do this in SQL 2012.   Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1345656-2799-1.aspx

> There's the problem. If he's db owner he can do anything he likes to
>   the database. If that's too many rights, start by removing him from
>   db_owner and cutting down permissions to the minimum he should have